# How do I solve this complexity equation,T(n) = T(n-3)+T(n-5)

Tags: difference-equations

While solving a puzzle, I ended up having a complexity of `T(n)=T(n-3)+T(n-5)`.
I was trying subtraction method. But I am unable to solve this. Please explain what should be the procedure.

Comment: This is a [linear homogeneous difference equation with constant coeffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients).

Comment: I am unable to relate this as am I not from CS background.

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking here; what are you trying to solve? Do you want to find a closed form for `T(n)`? What do you mean with “complexity equation”? This sounds more like a maths problem to me.

Comment: @poke Finally it should be something like T(n) = log(n)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a maths problem which is off-topic for SO and probably fits better on [Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [linear homogeneous difference equation with constant coeffs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients). It is usually solved by transforming it to the complex plane and solving a polynomial.

Without a CS background (as you state), I'm afraid the details wouldn't fit in here. Start with the Wikipedia entry, if you're interested.

If you want to skip to the final solution, here is the [Wolfram Alpha for it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%3DT%28n-3%29%2BT%28n-5%29).